# Chaining "in" clauses with mongomapper (and plucky)

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongomapper

I have a rails app with mongo that I query via mongomapper.

I would like to add two `$in` clauses to my query in different parts of my application. Eg:

```
def where_clause1
  where(app_ids: {'$in' => [5, 42, 23]})
end

def where_clause2
  where(app_ids: {'$in' => [44, 5, 87]})
end
```

I would like both clauses to be mutually exclusive.

But if I do:

```
$> User.where_clause1
=> #<MongoMapper::Plugins::Querying::DecoratedPluckyQuery 
     app_ids: {"$in"=>[5, 42, 23]}, transformer: ...>
$> User.where_clause2
=> #<MongoMapper::Plugins::Querying::DecoratedPluckyQuery 
     app_ids: {"$in"=>[44, 5, 87]}, transformer: ...>
# so far so good

#But:
$> User.where_clause1.where_clause2
=> #<MongoMapper::Plugins::Querying::DecoratedPluckyQuery 
     app_ids: {"$in"=>[5, 42, 23, 44, 87]}, transformer: ...>
```

If I chain two where clauses with `$in` inside, plucky does a union on the app_ids and merges the two `$in` clauses. I  would like an intersection instead, that is: `[5]`.

How can I achieve this ? I tried `User.where(...).andWhere(...)` but that doesn't exist. I don't want to manually intersect the two app_ids lists myself.

Answer (score 2):

What you have to consider is how this "chaining" is actually implemented. So in fact this is really just a "deep merge" of the arguments passed in which is why the "union" behavior is observed here.

Specifically there is [this code](https://github.com/mongomapper/plucky/blob/master/lib/plucky/query.rb#L161-L163), also listed here for posterity:

```
  def where(hash={})
    clone.tap { |query| query.criteria.merge!(CriteriaHash.new(hash)) }
  end
```

So if you expect some kind of "intersection" here then you are best off implementing your own method to do so. The behavior here is to "merge" any existing arguments that may be present in the query as a result of other direct operations.